# updating cart via button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to be on that page right before the checkout, where you can modify the quantity and update all the prices accordingly. Now my "Update" button, updates 'something' but it's not what i'm trying to achieve, it sends me on a line_items show page that i don't even want to have (i'm keeping it for now to avoid the missing template error). The rails documentation isn't helping me ... well anyway, the code is this

```
<ul>
    <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
        <%= form_for(item) do |f| %>
            <li><%= f.number_field :quantity, :value => item.quantity %> x <%= item.product.name %>
                <%= item.total_price %> </li>
        <% end %>
        <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
    <% end %>
    <br><strong>Total Price:</strong> <%= @cart.total_price %>
</ul>
<%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> 
<%= link_to 'Back', categories_path %>
```

Thank you !

**edited**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id, :order_id)
    end

end
```

Comment: It looks like you've got lots of code that you don't understand the purpose of.  Have you copied all of this from somewhere?  Are you working through a tutorial or something?

Comment: Hello, actually i wrote all of this page, even that Update button that i wanted to implement. Yes i don't quite understand all - i only started 2 weeks ago, and i did check out Agile's book, this is where i got the line_items model idea from. I would probably say i shouldn't even use an update button, but rather some ajax (which i don't much about). I guess i just figured out that, i shouldn't use the submit_tag, but rather a button, as submit sends me to the show page. This still doesn't solve my problem however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do redirect after you update an item. And provide correct `line_item_update_params` method that permites `quantity` param. Your controller should look like that:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    item.update(line_item_update_params)

    redirect_to :back # this is the key line of code
  end

  ...

  private

  # it is used for creating
  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id, :order_id)
  end

  # it is used for updating
  def line_item_update_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity)
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: Hello, this opened my eyes on how redirecting works !! And now i have a better sense of what's going on in the background. Thank you. But this wasn't the question actually .. the real problem is the fact that the button does not update the line - quantity and price wise. Researching around i ran across hidden_field_tags but i have failed to find a solution yet.

Comment: To help you with your problem I need to see your items_controller.rb file

Comment: hey, i think you meant the line_items controller. i've added it

Comment: Just edited my answer. The problem is with permitted attributes.

Comment: thank youuu ! it works now ! and i've learned 2 new things after this experience, the permitted attributes on updates (i thought the first permission was enough), and that thing about routing/redirection ! now just 99999 other things left to learn that i don't know about yet :D

Comment: You'r welcome ! It is sometimes not necessary to provide two methods (one for create and one for update). Your code would work too if you add :quantity attribute into the permit list of your `line_item_params` method and use it for updating as well as for creating. But in your case having two separate sets of permitted attributes is better solution while your model needs different parameters for updating and creating.